# How to find the angle situated in the intersection between two bisector segments?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> Find the value of the angle labeled $x$ in the figure from below.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&70^{\circ}\\
2.&85^{\circ}\\
3.&120^{\circ}\\
4.&95^{\circ}\\
5.&130^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

I've attempted to solve this problem but the only thing which I could recall is that the sum of the interior angles in a quadrilateral is $360^{\circ}$ but nothing else than that. What sort of identity can be used to solve this problem?.

**Please include a drawing in your answer** as I think this might require some sort of construction. But more importantly, **can this be solved relying only in euclidean geometry?.** Please try to give an explanation step-by-step as it becomes difficult for me to catch up with figures.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for extra constructions. Recall that the sum of interior angles of a polygon is given by
$$(n-2)\times180^\circ$$

where $n$ is its number of sides. This applies for convex and concave polygons.

First consider the angle sum of the triangle. We have:

$$80^\circ + (180^\circ - 2\theta) + (180^\circ - 2\beta) = 180^\circ$$

$$\theta + \beta = 130^\circ$$

Now consider the angle sum of the concave hexagon. We have:
$$x+90^\circ + \theta + (360^\circ - 80^\circ) + \beta + 90^\circ = (6-2)\times 180^\circ = 720^\circ$$

$$x+\theta + \beta = 260^\circ$$

$$x = 260^\circ - (\theta + \beta) = 260^\circ - 130^\circ =130^\circ$$

The rest of your recent questions can be solved by very similar methods.

Comment: A variation of this solution is, the sum of the two angles at the bottom of the pentagon is $\theta + \beta$ plus the sum of the two unknown angles of the triangle ($180^\circ-80^\circ$), and the sum of the remaining three angles of the pentagon is $x + 180^\circ$, and the five angles together must add up to $(5-2)\times180^\circ$.